# What will the "key" parameter hold when assigned to "row, col" as shown in the code below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following is a class that customizes how to get elements of multidimensional arrays

```
class array:
    def __init__(self, m,n):
        self._rows = []
        for _ in range(m):
            self._rows.append([0]*n)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        row, col = key
        return self._rows[row][col]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        row, col = key
        self._rows[row][col] = value
```

Comment: It is some sort of a two-element container, e.g., a two-character string, a list, or a tuple. Also, please follow the convention and capitalize class names.

Comment: But is such assignment in python possible, considering for example `a,b = 3` produces an error

Comment: Because 3 is not a two-element container. Please read again what I said.

Comment: @DYZ You're right, though it can't be a string since `self._rows` is a 2D list.

Comment: @wjandrea In this context, no, it cannot be a string. But in general, it could.

Comment: This is called [unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/) and it's covered in the official docs here: [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) under "Assignment of an object to a target list"

Comment: Not enough information  - can you show how it is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to assign a single element to multiple elements, you get an error:

```
a, b = 3  # doesn't work
```

However, python supports "multiple assignment", meaning that if you have the same number of elements on either side, you can assign corresponding ones:

```
a, b = 3, 4   # a = 3, b = 4
```

Lists and tuples work as well:

```
a, b = [3, 4]
a, b = (3, 4)
```

Your code:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    row, col = key
    return self._rows[row][col]
```

assumes that `key` is a tuple/list/other iterable of at least length 2, and tries to decompose it into its component parts, assigning them respectively to `row` and `col`.

Comment: I now understand, I was confusing multiple assignments and though the `a,b =3` would be equiavalent to  `row, col = key` . Thanks.